# How do I make a div both scrollable and clickable?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
<div id="menuContainer"></div>

<div id="menuItemTemplate" class="menuItem">
    <div class="menuItemTitle"></div>
    <div class="menuItemImage"><img src="resources/BlackRightChevron.png"/></div>
</div>
```

The **menuContainer** div is dynamically appended with clones of the **menuItemTemplate**. The current click event:

```
menuContainer.addEventListener('click',menuContainer_click,false);
```

does not fire when **menuContainer** overflows in the y-axis. 
So I implemented some [code found else where on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398733/phonegap-jqm-android-scroll-issue).

Which makes it scrollable but the click events do not run (probably because of the `preventDefault()`s). Without them I figure every event would be registered as a click instead of a possible move.

Oh, I'm using jQuery mobile and it's UI as well.
Is there any solution to my problem?

The changes I made as per the suggestion:

```
var scrollStartPosY=0;

document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
    scrollStartPosY=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
    event.preventDefault();
},false);

document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    this.scrollTop=scrollStartPosY-event.touches[0].pageY;
    event.preventDefault();

    move = true;
},false);

document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("touchend", function(event) {
if(move)
    move = false;
else
    menuContainer_Click(event);

},false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the preventDefaults are wiping out your click. In any case you're using click/mousedown/touchstart to scroll exclusively.

What I think you should do is register a touchend event to trigger whatever you intend to have the current click event do.  You may want to verify whether there has been a scroll in the meantime and if so, ignore the touchend.  That would differentiate between the two separate intentions of scrolling and clicking.

Comment: Will try that out now.

Comment: Tried setting a flag when a touchmove even occurs to true and when the touchend event occurs set that flag to false. If a touchend event occurs and the flag is already false then it runs the intended action.

That idea doesn't work. I'll put the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Decided that iScroll was just an easier solution. Though having difficulty with only one div not scrolling completely to the "bottom".